# Java Do-While Loop with Sentinel Value = -1 Not Terminating

Tags: java, do-while, terminate, sentinel

My professor and I cannot seem to understand why the do-while loop with a sentinel value of -1 is not terminating.  The do-while loop continues to loop even after the sentinel value of -1 is entered for employeeID.  Can someone please help?

Is there something wrong with my sentinel value?  Is it because I am using a switch statement?

Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Ass4_WeeklyPayrollTaxGuideWhileLoopIf_Scanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        int withExempt, employeeID;
        double hourlyWage, hoursWorked, currentEarnings, taxFICA, withExemptAmount;
        double previousYTD, adjWeeklyIncome, currentYTD, taxFederal, payTakeHome;
        String input;
        char maritalStatus;

        System.out.print("Enter employee id number: ");
        employeeID = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $");
        hourlyWage = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
        hoursWorked = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number of withholding exemptions: ");
        withExempt = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out
                .print("Enter marital status: [For married, enter m. " + "For single, enter s.] ");
        input = keyboard.next();
        maritalStatus = input.charAt(0);
        System.out.print("Enter previous year-to-date earnings: $");
        previousYTD = keyboard.nextDouble();

        while (employeeID != -1) {
            if (hoursWorked > 40)
                currentEarnings = ((hoursWorked - 40) * hourlyWage * 1.5) + (40 * hourlyWage);
            else
                currentEarnings = (hourlyWage * hoursWorked);

            taxFICA = (currentEarnings * 0.062) + (currentEarnings * 0.0145);
            withExemptAmount = withExempt * 51.92;
            adjWeeklyIncome = currentEarnings - withExemptAmount;
            currentYTD = currentEarnings + previousYTD;
            taxFederal = 0;

            switch (maritalStatus) {
            case 's':
            case 'S':
                if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 51)
                    taxFederal = 0;
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 517)
                    taxFederal = ((adjWeeklyIncome - 51) * 0.15);
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 1105)
                    taxFederal = (69.90 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 517) * 0.28));
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 2493)
                    taxFederal = (234.54 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 1105) * 0.31));
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 5385)
                    taxFederal = (664.82 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 2493) * 0.36));
                else
                    taxFederal = (1705.94 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 5385) * 0.396));
                break;

            case 'm':
            case 'M':
                if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 124)
                    taxFederal = 0;
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 899)
                    taxFederal = ((adjWeeklyIncome - 124) * 0.15);
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 1855)
                    taxFederal = (116.25 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 899) * 0.28));
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 3084)
                    taxFederal = (383.93 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 1855) * 0.31));
                else if (adjWeeklyIncome <= 5439)
                    taxFederal = (764.92 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 3084) * 0.36));
                else
                    taxFederal = (1612.72 + ((adjWeeklyIncome - 5439) * 0.396));
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("Incorrect entry for marital status.");
            }

            payTakeHome = currentEarnings - taxFICA - taxFederal;

            System.out.print("\n\tPayroll information" + "\n\t-----------------"
                    + "\n\tEmployee id:  " + employeeID + "\n\tCurrent earnings: $"
                    + formatter.format(currentEarnings) + "\n\tYear-to-date earnings: $"
                    + formatter.format(currentYTD) + "\n\tFICA taxes: $" + formatter.format(taxFICA)
                    + "\n\tFederal income tax withheld: $" + formatter.format(taxFederal)
                    + "\n\tTake home pay check amount: $" + formatter.format(payTakeHome));

            System.out.print("\n\nEnter employee id number: ");
            employeeID = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $");
            hourlyWage = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter hours worked: ");
            hoursWorked = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter number of withholding exemptions: ");
            withExempt = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print(
                    "Enter marital status: [For married, enter m. " + "For single, enter s.] ");
            input = keyboard.next();
            maritalStatus = input.charAt(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create **MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: Code formatting also matters a lot. Please strive to improve your posted code's formatting so that we can more easily read it since this can only help you get answers.

Comment: @stsutsui, your sentinel value is working just fine, you need to input the rest of the values before condition is checked. You might want reconsider your logic to make it work differently. By the way you have simple while loop in your example, not the do-while one you mentioned.

Comment: @Eugene I started with a do while loop, but then changed it to a while loop, since it didn't work.  I pasted the wrong code.  Aaaaaaa... I see what you are saying.  It's sad that my professor didn't seem to get that. Thanks!